# Change PHP ini values using provisioning

Tags: php, vagrant, homestead, php-ini, vagrant-provision

What is the best way to change PHP ini values when provisioning a Homestead box?

E.g. I want to change the value of `display_startup_errors` to `On`.

Would you find/replace the value in the `php.ini` file using `sed`?

Do I just put the commands in `after.sh` or is it better to use `config.vm.provision "shell"`?

Comment: PHP can read multiple ini files.  There's normally an ini.d directory or similar.  Check your current config with phpinfo(). It will tell you where configs are being loaded from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this with sed via `after.sh`. That's exactly what that script is for. That way you don't have to worry about changing any files that Homestead may overwrite in a future update.